# How to set a timing event for a mousedown event in jquery?

Tags: jquery

THE CODE SHOULD BE LIKE
$("#btn").mousedown().delay(2000);
Is it possible to bind a delay function to mousedown or is there another way to do it??Please HELP ME out

Comment: explain more about your need. Question is not sufficient to give an answer

Comment: Please tell us, what are you looking for? Delaying mousedown handler or what?

Comment: Yes i need to delay a mousedown event for 2 seconds and print a particular result?

Answer (score 1):

No, but you can do this:

```
var easyWayOut = 'string cheese';
$("#btn").mousedown(function(){
    setTimeout(function(){ 
        // do something here
        alert(easyWayOut);
    },2000);
 });
```

Also, you can do this if you want to animate something:

```
 $("#btn").mousedown(function(){
    $(this).fadeOut().delay(2000).fadeIn();
 });
```

Comment: I did it but ,can u tell me how to use a variable declared inside settimeout() outside that function

Comment: just declare the variable outside and use it inside as well as outside

Comment: could you write the code for me,i tried it many times but it doesnt work fa me,so i ended up in this kind of ques

Comment: i want a variable of the setimeout () to be used ooutside the function